# How do I get padding between table cells, but not around the entire table?

Tags: html, padding, css-tables, spacing

I want to have a table with padding ***between*** each of the cells, but not around the outer edge cells, that is, not around the table itself.

Using:

```
border-collapse : separate;
border-spacing  : 0.5em;
```

gives me padding everywhere, while using:

```
border-collapse : collapse;
```

gives no padding anywhere.

Attempting an alternate approach, I can get padding solely *between* the cells *horizontally* using a `td + td` selector. However I can't use a `tr + tr` selector because it seems `tr` ignores margin, padding and border rules.

And, of course, padding on a plain `td` selector applies to all cells, even the outer-edges of the outer cells.

This only has to work for current-generation browser - no IE 6 or 7 for me thank you very much.  And I am not going to loose any sleep over IE 8, though it would be nice if that worked.

Comment: But IE7 or IE8?  (i.e.  no `:last-child` answers?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution, as it uses padding instead of border spacing.  Possibly it will work for your problem though.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
table {
    border: 1px red solid;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

td {
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px black solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

tr:first-child td {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

tr:last-child td {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**Produces:**

[image]

Also [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PakKK/13/).

Comment: Actually, that looks *precisely* like what I am looking for - I was not aware that there is a `last-child` pseudo-class.

Comment: Yes, but I warned you:  [It only works > IE8.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild) :(

Comment: Nice, but this not working with colspan and rowspan in a complex table. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Can you fiddle with the markup to add .first to the first cell in a row and .last to the last, and I guess also to the first and last rows, and then pad appropriately?

Comment: Not realistically - it would be a significant effort and a maintenance nightmare.